# Ngrok Server failed to allocate tunnel: Invalid authtoken your-token

Tags: ngrok

Unable to tunnel using ngrok. Getting below error. 
Server failed to allocate tunnel: Invalid authtoken your-token

Anyone faced this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue and emailed the developer, who allowed me into the 2.0 beta which fixes the problem.

Comment: In case you face it again, you may try to delete the ngrok config file which stores the auth token.  Default location /User/username/.ngrok2/ngrok.yml  or /User/username/.ngrok  . For more read https://ngrok.com/docs#config-location